# andfilterwhere for multiple selection in yii2

Tags: sql, yii2

How can i customize the below query for multiple select status filter in a array using Yii2

```
Query: SELECT FROM STATUS WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I need to convert above code like below FilterWhere format

Code:

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
            'status' => $this->status
        ]);
```

I need to filter for multiple status.

Comment: Please edit your query and/or code to make them consistent. Is `status` a column or a table name? Or is `id` a column name?

Answer (score 1):

This will help you ...

```
 $query->andFilterWhere([ 'in','status',$this->status]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$query->where(['id' => [1,2,3,4]]);
```